# JTabbedPane Preferred Size increasing when adding tabs

Tags: java

I have a dialog with several JTabbedPanes that can be minimized/maximized. However I have an issue when the tab is in minimized mode.

A small example of the code:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
JPanel main = new JPanel();
main.setLayout(new BoxLayout(main, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel();
JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     tabPane.addTab("Test" + i, new JPanel());
     System.out.println(tabPane.getPreferredSize().height);
}  

tabPanel.add(tabPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

main.add(tabPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

dialog.add(main);

dialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

What I expected was a tab pane to be the smallest size possible, but  I noticed that as I added more tabs, the height of the tabbed pane was increasing. This was the result from the print statement:

37, 55, 73, 91, 109

The fact that the height is increasing when tabs are added does not seem right to me since according to the documentation in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html, "The preferred size of the tabbed pane is just big enough to display its tallest child at its preferred height, and its widest child at its preferred width." I would expect that since I'm adding empty panels, the size would not change, but this does not seem to be the case. Is there anyway around this?

FYI, I am using the latest version of Java.